# Proper way for reminders in windows 8 modern ui

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, alert

I am developing a windows 8 modern UI and I have to implement a reminder functionality. After googling I have found that ScheduleToastNotifications are good to use, I download the sample from 
[here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Scheduled-notifications-da477093). After reading the documentation of ScheduleToastNotifications I found the limitations, you can make a  notification to repeat only for an hour and you can add only 4096 notifications of this type. So I took a decision of memorizing the reminder inside a sqllite db and showing it in the UI, but my problem just moved along, I don't see a way of querying the system scheduled notifications that are memorized after the notification that I scheduled pops it out. One solution that came into my mind was with BackgroundTask but there are also limitations in that as well, last but not least would be the use of LiveCalendar, but that will mean that a connection to the internet would be required that's not quite a solution for me. Also I found about MaintenanceTrigger that would be a solution but it has to have AC power connector plugged in.

So my question is what is the proper way of adding the reminder functionality inside a windows 8 app? I know that in WindowsPhone there is a Scheduler namespace along with the Alert class that do all the dirty work for you.

Thanks in advance!